# JQuery newbie - dialog

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the jqueryui dialog (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) within my html page.

Has anyone got any links on the web to the javascript libraries needed to use the dialog widget?

My HTML code taken from (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-message.html) is below - I think linking to the javascript libraries is the problem..

Please help, many thanks.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal message</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="/css/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui.draggable.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/external/bgiframe/jquery.bgiframe.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="/css/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<div id="dialog" title="Download complete">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
        Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
    </p>
    <p>
        Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
    </p>

</div>

<!-- Sample page content to illustrate the layering of the dialog -->
<div class="hiddenInViewSource" style="padding:20px;">
    <p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
    <form>
        <input value="text input" /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" />checkbox<br />
        <input type="radio" />radio<br />

        <select>
            <option>select</option>
        </select><br /><br />
        <textarea>textarea</textarea><br />
    </form>
</div><!-- End sample page content -->

</div><!-- End demo -->

<div class="demo-description">

<p>Use a modal dialog to explicitly acknowledge information or an action before continuing their work.  Set the <code>modal</code> option to true, and specify a primary action (Ok) with the <code>buttons</code> option.</p>

</div><!-- End demo-description -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/

It's also the UI link at the top of the page.

You can use the "custom download builder" to download only what you need.  You will need UI Core and Dialog.  I would recommend also downloading the jQuery release as well- sometimes the library depends on the exact jQuery release.

The download will contain normal and minified versions.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're pointing to the wrong directory for your JavaScript UI files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui.draggable.js"></script>
```

Is it `/js/ui/...` or `/js/...`?

As for which libraries to use, you should only need:

- jquery-1.3.2.js
- ui.core.js
- ui.dialog.js

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries onto your server.  You can get them here:

- http://jquery.com/ (large button on right)
- http://jqueryui.com/download (select UI core and dialog - optionally get draggable and resizable if you need that functionality)

According to your code ...

... you will need to put them into the /js folder of your site.

If you are testing the HTML locally, remove the "/" from "/js", make a "js" folder alongside the HTML file, and put your javascript files in there.

Answer (score 0):

I used the themeroller tool http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
With this tool I was able to download all the themes and js libraries needed to make the dialog work.

The javascript ajax libraries are also hosted on google servers.

The code is below for completeness:(referencing the css and javascript files downloaded from themeroller).

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){


    // Dialog   
    $('#dialog').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     width: 600,
     buttons: {
      "Ok": function() { 
       $(this).dialog("close"); 
      }, 
      "Cancel": function() { 
       $(this).dialog("close"); 
      } 
     }
    });

    // Dialog Link
    $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
     $('#dialog').dialog('open');
     return false;
    });

    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
     function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
     function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
    );

   });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
   /*demo page css*/
   body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
   .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
   #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
   #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
   ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
   ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
   ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
  </style> 
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Welcome to jQuery UI!</h1>
 <p style="font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.5; margin: 1em 0; width: 50%;">This page demonstrates the widgets you downloaded using the theme you selected in the download builder. We've included and linked to minified versions of <a href="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">jQuery</a>, your personalized copy of <a href="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js">jQuery UI (js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js)</a>, and <a href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css">css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css</a> which imports the entire jQuery UI CSS Framework. You can choose to link a subset of the CSS Framework depending on your needs. </p>
 <p style="font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.5; margin: 1em 0; width: 50%;">You've downloaded components and a theme that are compatible with jQuery 1.3+. Please make sure you are using jQuery 1.3+ in your production environment. <em>If you need jQuery UI components that work with an earlier version of jQuery, you can choose an older version in the <a href="http://jqueryui.com/download">jQuery UI download builder</a>.</em></p> 

 <p style="font-weight: bold; margin: 2em 0 1em; font-size: 1.3em;">YOUR COMPONENTS:</p>

  <!-- Dialog NOTE: Dialog is not generated by UI in this demo so it can be visually styled in themeroller-->
  <h2 class="demoHeaders">Dialog</h2>
  <p><a href="#" id="dialog_link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>Open Dialog</a></p>


  <!-- ui-dialog -->
  <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```